# Can't resolve YouTube class/symbol, YouTube Data API Java sample issue

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to execute the [Search by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword) sample code from YouTube Data API Java Samples collection.

In order to do that I:

1. Created a new project in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Downloaded latest [google-api-java-client-featured.zip](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download).
3. Added the libraries from the `google-api-java-client-featured` to the project via *Project Structure → Libraries → New Project Library*.
4. Created a class *Search.java* and copy pasted the [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword).

IDEA can't resolve `YouTube` class:

```java
/**
 * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
 * to make YouTube Data API requests.
 */
private static YouTube youtube;
```

Where can I find this `YouTube` class or what have I to do in order to be able to execute the official YouTube Data API Java sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is more to download. You got everything except the actual `YouTube Data API`. As of this writing it can be found at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3. At that site there is the option to download a `.zip` file, or obtain through `Maven` or `Gradle`.

I found it by searching (googling) for the class `com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube`, which I found listed as an import in the `Sample` that you linked above.

Comment: Your link works. It's very strange that they didn't published the link in the Download section: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download